# Command that works fine in terminal fails in cron

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to get cron to run a jar file. When I type the command, it works as expected:

```
root@ubuntu:~/AndKnucklesBot# cd /root/AndKnucklesBot; java -jar AndKnucklesBot.jar /root/knuxSecrets.txt
The Art of Interior Decoration & Knuckles
```

However when I set up cron using the following line (running every minute for debug purposes)

```
* * * * * cd /root/AndKnucklesBot; java -jar AndKnucklesBot.jar /root/knuxSecrets.txt
```

I get the following email in error:

```
From root@ubuntu.members.linode.com  Mon Sep  4 07:37:01 2017
Return-Path: <root@ubuntu.members.linode.com>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@ubuntu.members.linode.com
Received: by ubuntu.members.linode.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 9ACA866BE; Mon,  4 Sep 2017 07:37:01 +0000 (UTC)
From: root@ubuntu.members.linode.com (Cron Daemon)
To: root@ubuntu.members.linode.com
Subject: Cron <root@ubuntu> cd /root/AndKnucklesBot; java -jar AndKnucklesBot.jar /root/knuxSecrets.txt
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20170904073701.9ACA866BE@ubuntu.members.linode.com>
Date: Mon,  4 Sep 2017 07:37:01 +0000 (UTC)

/root/knuxSecrets.txt
```

I have a sneaking suspicion this has something to do with me having these files in root, and cron or the Java runtime not having permission to run them. However, I'm not familiar enough with the matter to identify the problem. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Someone asked for the inclusion of the result of `sudo file /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` so here it is:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

Comment: Specify the full path to `java`, it's likely the cron environment doesn't have that binary on it's `$PATH` variable

Comment: Tried "cd /root/AndKnucklesBot; /usr/bin/java -jar AndKnucklesBot.jar /root/knuxSecrets.txt", no dice…

Comment: Is anything being written to the error logs?

Comment: after you run the `cron` job, check what is written to `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Nothing seems interesting in syslog, but here it is anyway:
Sep  4 08:30:01 ubuntu CRON[9079]: (root) CMD (cd /root/AndKnucklesBot; /usr/bin/java -jar AndKnucklesBot.jar /root/knuxSecrets.txt^M)

Comment: I narrowed it down a little and it looks like the jar is running, but I'm getting a FileSystemException. I suspect something might be wrong with the permissions. But why would cron invoking java as root be any different than me invoking java as root?

Comment: I wonder if the crontab has the proper line endings. Can you [edit] the question to include the results of `sudo file /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`?